# WCF Announcements: Modify when to send announcements

Tags: wcf, discovery

Microsoft says that you can customize announcement [functionality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee620626(v=vs.110).aspx).

Does anyone have experience on modifying when to send online announcements? Can someone direct me to an example?

I've tried using the AnnounceOnline method but there must be a problem with my code since I get an error indicating that "the target machine refused it"

Answer (score 0):

If this could help anyone, here's my answer:

```
Private Sub AnnounceService()
    Dim baseAddress As New Uri(String.Format("net.tcp://{0}:10000", Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Net.Dns.GetHostName).AddressList(1).ToString()))
    Dim serviceHost As New ServiceHost(GetType(WCFService), baseAddress)
    Dim endPoint As ServiceEndpoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IWCFService), New NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), "WCFService")
    Dim epAddress As New EndpointAddress(baseAddress)

    Dim client As New AnnouncementClient(New UdpAnnouncementEndpoint())
    Dim epDiscoveryMetaData = EndpointDiscoveryMetadata.FromServiceEndpoint(endPoint)

    client.AnnounceOnline(epDiscoveryMetaData)

End Sub
```